# View IMDb top lists sorted by demographics to give more personalized ratings

Tags: sorting, imdb

How do I view the IMDb top lists sorted by demographics in order to get more personalized ratings?

For example, I would find it more useful if I could view the Top 250 films list, while counting votes only for males, and even more if I could look at the top votes for males in a specific age bracket.

Comment: Please check an updated (2019) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the top 50:  <strike>[Votes by males](http://www.imdb.com/chart/male)</strike>

Note:  To get to this page, I clicked on the <strike>[Tops at the Box Office](http://www.imdb.com/Charts/)</strike> link and chose Votes by Gender on the left side.

Comment: Nice, that is one step closer! I forgot to mention it in my question, but I was hoping to also look at age ranges - not sure if this is possible though.

Answer (score 0):

### 2019 Update

**It is now possible to also look at age ranges.**

As per OP requested in his [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/view-imdb-top-lists-sorted-by-demographics-to-give-more-personalized-ratings#comment3442_4172):

> *"...I was hoping to also look at age ranges - not sure if this is possible though."*

Also. By now the links provided in an [earlier answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/4172/117311) have changed.

- **You now can find them under: `(movie title)` --> `Menu` --> `User Ratings`**

[image: imdb user ratings]

- **Once there you click on the table for detailed results.**

[image: imdb ratings males 18-29]

- **Although, looking closely at the results, the numbers do NOT quite add up.**

[image: imdb ratings]